# How to iterate through dataframe and append predictions?

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to implement a Naive Bayesian classifier model to predict labels for a trading year. I manage to create the model and predictions, but what is the best way to append to a dataframe so i can calculate the confusion matrix?

This is what I have so far...

```
X = df_one[['mean_return', 'volatility']].values
Y = df_one[['labels']]
NB_classifier = GaussianNB().fit(X, Y)

lst = []

for n in df_two.itertuples():
    new_instance = np.asmatrix([n[-3], n[-2]])
    prediction = NB_classifier.predict(new_instance)
    lst.append(prediction.tolist())
```

But the issue here is that it is coming out as a list of lists, so like this...

```
[['green'],
 ['green'],
 ['red'],
 ['red'],
 ['green'],
 ['green'],
 ['green'],
 ['red'],
 ['red'],
```

```
    Week_Number Year    Open    Close   mean_return volatility  labels  Pred_Labels
53  1   2021    111.262000  111.403999  1.48140 2.957447    green    [green]
54  2   2021    119.343999  119.638001  0.63940 3.647642    green   [green]
55  3   2021    117.622500  116.032499  -0.56600    3.025880    red [red]
56  4   2021    108.176001  105.146001  -2.40900    2.796566    red [red]
57  5   2021    113.886000  115.904002  3.22440 5.836319    green   [green]
58  6   2021    122.692000  124.023999  0.94120 3.489483    green   [green]
```

All I want is a list of values ['green', 'red', 'green'] etc so I can compare it to my real labels.

How do I go about doing this?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please share a small reproducible sample of your data set?

Comment: shared @AnoushiravanR

Comment: And what is `df_two` here that you used in your for loop?

Comment: the exact same minus the 'Pred_Labels' column

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
import numpy as np


pred = np.array(lst).reshape(1, -1).tolist()[0]
df['Pred_Labels'] = pred
```